# Right click drag drop not working

Tags: windows-7, right-click

I used to be able to right click and drag and drop into a new folder.

To move a group of files into a new folder using tortoisehg source control.

The right click drag drop doesn't seem to be working.

On doing some research people are suggesting that a window management addon breaks right click drag.

I don't think I have installed anything like this.

Any tips to help diagnose why right click drag drop is not working.

Comment: Uninstall tortoisehg, see if the problem goes away, report the problem to the  tortoisehg developer.

Answer (score 4):

Bizarrely, I came across this [post](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/299845-my-drag-drop-function-not-working.html):

Which suggests holding down right click and pressing esc.

I thought it was a joke at first, as I've never heard of that short cut.

It worked.

Comment: Does anyone have an explanation of what Windows is actually doing? I'd like to know what it's killing/reloading/whatever to restore this functionality and why it's dying in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do not have damaged DLL's (I did not), the fix is ridiculously simple... hit the ESC key twice. I'm not sure how it get's "disabled" but this has happened to me twice, and both times, hitting ESC twice (quickly) returns the right click drag and drop back to normal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hitting ESC twice solves it for me (on Windows 10, issue is obviously not resolved yet).